NodeRed find bottlenecks / identify slow nodes, functions etc
I am using NodeRed since quite some time now and everything is getting bigger and bigger.
Lately I implemented something that was quite "expensice" and slowed down everything else.
Of course now I knew where to look / what to delete, to bring speed back to normal... but it made me wonder:
What if you don't know where to look?
What is the best method to find bottlenecks in NodeRed or how to identidy slow "tabs" or "functions" etc.
What do you use?

You can increase the logging level in your settings.js file to 'trace' or 'debug', and set metrics to true. To find specific "tabs" or "functions", I would disable all tabs/functions and then enable them individually to find the bottlenecks.
logging: {
    /** Only console logging is currently supported */
    console: {
        /** Level of logging to be recorded. Options are:
         * fatal - only those errors which make the application unusable should be recorded
         * error - record errors which are deemed fatal for a particular request + fatal errors
         * warn - record problems which are non fatal + errors + fatal errors
         * info - record information about the general running of the application + warn + error + fatal errors
         * debug - record information which is more verbose than info + info + warn + error + fatal errors
         * trace - record very detailed logging + debug + info + warn + error + fatal errors
         * off - turn off all logging (doesn't affect metrics or audit)
         */
        level: "trace",
        /** Whether or not to include metric events in the log output */
        metrics: true,
        /** Whether or not to include audit events in the log output */
        audit: false
    }
}


